# Error when calling jasper report in apex, acl is also created, but it still gives acl error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, jasperserver

I did everything in this article:

https://pretius.com/blog/jaspersoft-apex-integration

But when running, I encounter an acl error, and even though I created an acl, it still gives me the same error, what should I do?

I use Oracle 11g, Apex 21, Tomcat 9, and Jasper Server 7.5.

this code use in apex:

```
DECLARE
  v_blob                 BLOB;
  v_file_type            VARCHAR2 (25) :='pdf';
  v_file_name            VARCHAR2 (25) := 'employee.'||v_file_type;
  v_vcContentDisposition VARCHAR2 (25)  := 'inline';
  v_DEPTNO               NUMBER := :P10_DEPTNO;
  v_hostname   VARCHAR2(30) := 'localhost'; -- your hostname, eg: localhost
  v_port       NUMBER       := '5080'; -- port for your JasperReports Server, eg: 8081
  v_username   VARCHAR2(50) := 'anonymousUser'; -- jasperreports server username 
  v_password   VARCHAR2(50) := 'anonymousUser'; -- jaspereports server password
  v_jasper_string VARCHAR2(30) := v_username || ';' || v_password;
  v_login_url  VARCHAR2(100) := 'http://' || v_hostname || ':' || v_port || '/jasperserver/rest/login';
  v_report_url VARCHAR2(100) := 'http://' || v_hostname || ':' || v_port || '/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/' || v_file_name;
BEGIN
  -- log into jasper server
  v_blob := apex_web_service.make_rest_request_b(
    p_url => v_login_url,
    p_http_method => 'GET',
    p_parm_name => apex_util.string_to_table('j_username;j_password',';'),
    p_parm_value => apex_util.string_to_table(v_jasper_string,';')
  );
  -- download file
  v_blob := apex_web_service.make_rest_request_b(
    p_url => v_report_url,
    p_http_method => 'GET',
    p_parm_name => apex_util.string_to_table('p_dept',';'),
    p_parm_value => apex_util.string_to_table(v_DEPTNO,';')
  );
  --OWA_UTIL.mime_header ('application/pdf', FALSE);  -- view your pdf file
  OWA_UTIL.MIME_HEADER( 'application/octet', FALSE ); -- download your pdf file
  HTP.p('Content-Length: ' || DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(v_blob));
  HTP.p('Content-Disposition: ' || v_vcContentDisposition ||'; filename="' || v_file_name || '"');
  OWA_UTIL.http_header_close;
  WPG_DOCLOAD.DOWNLOAD_FILE(v_blob);
  APEX_APPLICATION.STOP_APEX_ENGINE;

END;
```

and this error:

1 error has occurred
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1339 ORA-29261: bad argument ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1284 ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130 ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)

Thank you for helping me

Comment: "... even though I created an acl, it still gives me the same error, what should I do?" Looks like you didn't create it (the ACL) correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You may get answer from this below blog.,
[https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/jasper-server-and-apex-integration-getting-ora-06512-9129'](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/jasper-server-and-apex-integration-getting-ora-06512-9129%27)

```
And., I got success by this below code
 g_user_agent VARCHAR2(255) := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/A.B (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/X.Y.Z.W Safari/A.B.';
    v_url          varchar2(4000);
    v_request      sys.utl_http.req;
    v_response      sys.utl_http.resp;
    v_file          blob;
    v_download      raw(32767);
    v_mime_header  varchar2(64) ;
    nm  owa.vc_arr;
    vl  owa.vc_arr;

BEGIN
    -- init the cgi environment
    nm(1) := 'DUMMY_JUST_TO_SET_UP_OWA_UTIL';
    vl(1) := 'WHATEVER';
    owa.init_cgi_env( nm.count, nm, vl );

    v_url := 'http://myUser:myPwd@myHost:myPort/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/'||p_report_name||'?'||p_parameter; 

    v_request := sys.utl_http.begin_request(v_url);
    sys.utl_http.set_header(v_request, 'User-Agent', g_user_agent);
    v_response := sys.utl_http.get_response(v_request); 

    dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_file, TRUE, dbms_lob.session); 

    LOOP
    BEGIN
      sys.utl_http.read_raw(v_response, v_download);
      dbms_lob.writeappend(v_file, utl_raw.length(v_download), v_download);
      EXCEPTION WHEN sys.utl_http.end_of_body THEN
        EXIT;
      END;
    END LOOP; 

    sys.utl_http.end_response(v_response);

    owa_util.mime_header('application/' || nvl(p_output_format,'octet'), false);
    htp.p('Content-length: ' || dbms_lob.getlength(v_file));
    htp.p('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' || p_report_name || '.'|| p_output_format ||'"');
    owa_util.http_header_close;

    wpg_docload.download_file(v_file); 

    dbms_lob.freetemporary(v_file);



Please refer https://www.eehelp.com/question/download-jasperserver-for-apex/
```